# windows service is not accepting credentials once machine is restarted

Tags: windows-services, startup, credentials

I have a windows service created that's up and running fine. But once the machine is restarted/logged of and logged in The service just fails to start and logs "1069 logon error". But there is a workaround for this. Go to service properties ,click on "Log on " tab  and and provide my password once again eventhough Password fields appear to display *s (means password I already set).

My question is Why windows service is not accepting my credentials which was already saved there before logoff/restart and why I have to give it manually every time when need to start.

Can someone help me out on this please?

Thanks in Advance,

PrJ

Answer (score 0):

Is this computer part of a domain? Maybe the [group policy is overwriting the local policy](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/windows-service-forgets-password/).